# PeopleSoft login in issue

Tags: peoplesoft

Hi all we are building a portal at work.  When the user logs on to the portal he/she can press a button which will re-direct them to a peoplesoft webpage.  This works fine however when the user only closes the tab in the peoplesoft webpage and doesn't sign out he/she has an issue re-visiting the peoplesoft page again.  For example; user logs on to portal --> clicks button -->( (A)cmd=pslogin logs in if required) redirected to peoplesoft page -->closes tab (doesn't sign out)--> goes to tab with portal --> click button --> peoplesoft page doesn't load blank screen comes up.  The blank screen that comes up is the same as the one from before (A) however nothing appears.  I think the issue is that when the user closes the tab without logging out the session/cookies on the local machine are never removed.  Thank you

Comment: BTW I was thinking when the button is pressed check if the user has a session if they do remove their session and re-log them in.  I also wanted to try the javascript onclose method to log the user off when the user closes the tab but am going to have issues if the user refreshes, navigates from the page.  Also if you have a resources to read I would be very thankful.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your portal probably uses bypass signon.  This enables a guest user to automatically be logged in as a default user.  When that person is signed into PeopleSoft cookies get set, one of which is a session timeout cookie.  When the person revisits the site without logging out they still have that cookie and PeopleSoft sees they had a now invalid session and sends them to an error or login screen.

Are you linking directly to a tab page or some other component URL?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but I found out it had to do with our authenticating ticket.  but i got it all fixed